# Dynamic array size allocation

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

I had written below code in C. I expected error message since array size cannot be allocated dynamically. But the code compiles. But the result size of myArray1 is absurd. I am not sure why it compiles. I am using codeblock and minGW.

```
   int a;
    printf("Enter the value for a\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    int myArray2[a];
    printf("value of a = %d\tSize of myArray1 = %d",(sizeof(myArray2)/sizeof(myArray2[0])));
```

Comment: Not checking the specification, it may be valid for C11, and it may be included in GCC extension.

Comment: one correction here  printf("value of a = %d\tSize of myArray1 = %d",a, (sizeof(myArray2)/sizeof(myArray2[0])));

Comment: safer correction: `printf("value of a = %d\tSize of myArray1 = %u",a, (unsigned int)(sizeof(myArray2)/sizeof(myArray2[0]))); `

Comment: It should be `%zu` for the second parameter, not `%d` or `%u`.

Comment: better watch out when a<0

Comment: No, @PaulR, it should __not__ be `%zu`; this would be true for a POSIXly correct, or 100% ISO-C conforming platform, but the OP is writing for MS-Windows, which is neither. For the OP's case, this is misguided advice indeed, since Microsoft's `printf()` implementation explicitly __does not support__ the `z` format modifier: see the box-out note [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx)

Comment: @KeithMarshall: he says he's using minGW though, which I believe uses gcc ? Also `%zu` even seems to work (finally!) with recent versions of MSVC ?

Comment: Yes, @PaulR, MinGW is GCC for MS-Windows, but it uses the Microsoft runtime library, `MSVCRT.DLL`, which furnishes the default `printf()` implementation, so the `z` format modifier is unsupported, as documented in the MSDN reference I cited earlier.

Comment: OK - thanks - I didn't know that - I was pretty sure that Microsoft had finally caught up with C99 and started supporting `%zu`, but maybe not.

Comment: The operative phrase, in your last comment, @PaulR, is "last couple of _Visual Studio_ releases"; all the C99 additions require the non-free `MSVCR120.DLL` (or later) which accompanies those, and MinGW __cannot__ use that -- it isn't compatible with GCC's GPLv3 licence, so we have to use whichever version of `MSVCRT.DLL` is provided as an OS component. Besides, AFAICT from MSDN, even in `MSVCR120.DLL`, `printf()` doesn't support the `z` modifier.

Comment: Thanks again for the further clarification - it all makes more sense now as on the rare occasions that I have to work with Windows it's with Visual Studio and cygwin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C99 standard supports variable sized arrays on the stack.

Here is the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) on it:

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++. These arrays are declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that is not a constant expression. The storage is allocated at the point of declaration and deallocated when the block scope containing the declaration exits.